# How to find a href tag with a certain file format in BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the XML link from a website. An example page can be found here at `https://www.loc.gov/item/2015669100/`

Using below code, it only finds the PDF file link butnot the xml link.

```
productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'views'})
        for div in productDivs:
                xml = div.find('a')['href']
                if xml.endswith('xml'):
                        print(xml)
```

How do I get the XML file link?

Comment: are you trying to get the transcript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS Selector `nth-of-type(n)`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.loc.gov/item/2015669100/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

print('PDF:', soup.select_one('.views a:nth-of-type(1)')['href'])
print('XML:', soup.select_one('.views a:nth-of-type(2)')['href'])
```

---

Or use [`find_next_sibling()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
...
productDivs = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "views"})

for div in productDivs:
    pdf = div.find("a")
    xml = pdf.find_next_sibling("a")["href"]

    print("PDF:", pdf["href"])
    print("XML:", xml)
```

Output:

```
PDF: https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/afc/afc2010039/afc2010039_crhp0001_Carter_transcript/afc2010039_crhp0001_Carter_transcript.pdf
XML: https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/afc/afc2010039/afc2010039_crhp0001_Carter_transcript/afc2010039_crhp0001_Carter_transcript.xml
```